# The videos I have posted on youtube can't be displayed in HD

Tags: rendering

I create my videos using Blender, however when I uploaded them on youtube. They cant be displayed in HD... Do you know how may I solve this issue?

Best Regards

Comment: Did you render the videos at 1920 x 1080 with 100%?

Comment: Can they be displayed in HD locally, opening them with a video player like VLC or Windows Media Player?